# How do I run a Jquery method every midnight?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter. I have a PHP function called `AddPenalty();` in my controller.

Now in my jQuery I'd do something like this:

```
var DueDate; //this should have a Date Value

var d = new Date();

var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();

var now = d.getFullYear() + '/' +
    ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
    ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day;

if(DueDate == now){
    AddPenalty(); //call this function from controller
}
```

I want this script to be executed every Midnight. How should I do it? Also, how do I call controller function `AddPenalty()` in my jQuery?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Do you want to update something on your server? Do you want to update something in the browser while a user is viewing the page as midnight strikes? Both? Which midnight do you care about? The timezone the user is in or a fixed time zone?

Comment: It's a PHP method. Why would you be calling it from jquery?

Comment: Why don't you just use an equivalent in PHP and a cron job ? When does this javascript get executed ?

Comment: I'm trying to add a record in my database. that's what AddPenalty() does.

Comment: yeah it's a PHP method, that's why i'm asking also how to call it in jquery?

Comment: Keep coding server side and don't use client side scripting if you don't need anything from the user

Comment: @chrisjohn016 right, then you dont need any javascript. You just need to update the database directly from a php file and call that file in a cronjob

Comment: You can use ajax to execute PHP... but I don't think you wanna do this

Comment: Extremely risking doing this browser side, when you mess with database too.

Comment: @Alex okay I get it why it's risky. What would you suggest then? To implement it? I just want to execute AddPenalty() every midnight

Comment: okay @Steve. That's what I want. So I'll try to study cronjob then. haha lol. thanks guys

Answer (score 4):

Since jquery runs client side you could say it's not possible to create a cronjob.
Thankfully to PhantomJS we can create a cronjob with javascript. PhantomJS let's you simulate an webbrowser on your server so you can execute jquery/javascript codes.

Website: http://phantomjs.org/

Comment: If you need to run browser side JavaScript on a schedule, and you aren't doing automated testing, then you are probably doing something very wrong.

Comment: @Quentin I disagree. I've used it before to create highcharts with highcharts.js in a cronjob to create PDF's and then mail it to several users.

Comment: There are exceptions :) (This doesn't look like one though)

Comment: @Quentin You're right about that. Just giving the OP a suggestion.

Comment: what do you mean automated testing?

Comment: @Quentin, but wouldn't Phantom run server-side, like Daan suggests in his answer? If that is the case, then I don't understand your first comment about client-side JS. I think this is the right answer if OP doesn't feel comfortable writing native scripts on his server.

Comment: @chrisjohn016 — It is useful to test how a website behaves in a real browser to see if the website is working properly. It is useful to programatically control the browser because software is better at doing repetitive, boring tasks than humans.

Comment: @Goran_Mandic — Yes, but running a browser to load a webpage to run some Ajax to call a PHP script is incredibly complicated and inefficient when compared to running a command line PHP script directly (or calling the Ajax end point with the command line curl utility).

Comment: @Quentin, I understand completely. I was simply trying to reinforce Daan's point. I also didn't know that using phantomJS would have the same footprint as running a browser. I guess I'll take your word for it. Cheers.

Comment: @Goran_Mandic It's does exactly that running a browser, very light-weight. And it could become complicated for beginner webdevelopers. But it's a valid answer.

Comment: okay i have searched Phantom.js and it really confuses me. Which example should I follow with what I wanted to implement please? I also tried to search cronjob. I still need to check my server though.

Comment: First download and install it and do the Quick Start: http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html

Answer (score 3):

You have to do a CRON job, which will execute the file you defined every x minutes/hours/...